# Handle void method as object's property in React unit test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I would like to pass a value to a function which is a part of interface to force element to be clicked.
I have a piece of React code to which I want to write unit test:

```
const VariantItem = (props: VariantItem): ReactElement => {
return (
    <div key={props.productVariant.variantName} className="variant-list__variant" onClick={props.selectVariant}>
        ...some more of html
    </div>); }
```

I use interface which includes void method as property:

```
interface VariantItem {
productVariant: ProductVariant,
selectVariant: () => void   }
```

Eventually I try to test it with object like:

```
const testVariantItem: VariantItem = {
productVariant: testProductVariantItem (filled with some data),
selectVariant: null }
```

then call it with test:

```
   test('test', async () => {    
    const { container } = render (<VariantItem{ ...testVariantItem } />)
    await userEvent.click(container );
```

Is there any way to prepare test object with 'selectVariant' method mocked somehow? Click method seems not be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jest.fn()` to mock a function i.e.

```
const testVariantItem: VariantItem = {
productVariant: testProductVariantItem (filled with some data),
selectVariant: jest.fn(() => /* your mock  */) }
```